# SMS reminder app, Node/Twilio/Cron/Mongo: TypeError: Cannot read property 'utc' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongoose, cron, twilio, scheduler

I'm working off of some code in a Twilio tutorial, and everything seems to be working fine, except I'm not receiving any notifications. I get this error back after the Notifications Worker runs:

```
[grunt-develop] > (node:58755) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'utc' of undefined
```

Here is the appointment.js file that appears to be causing the error under AppointmentSchema.methods:

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var moment = require('moment');
    var twilio = require('twilio');



    var AppointmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      phoneNumber: String,
      notification : String,
      timeZone: String,
      time : {type : Date, index : true}
    });




AppointmentSchema.methods.requiresNotification = function (date) {
      return Math.round(moment.duration(moment(this.time).tz(this.timeZone).utc()
                              .diff(moment(date).utc())
                            ).asMinutes()) === this.notification;
    };


    AppointmentSchema.statics.sendNotifications = function(callback) {

      // now
      var searchDate = new Date();
      Appointment
        .find()
        .then(function (appointments) {
          appointments = appointments.filter(function(appointment) {
                  return appointment.requiresNotification(searchDate);
          });
          if (appointments.length > 0) {
            sendNotifications(appointments);
          }
        });

        // Send messages to all appoinment owners via Twilio
        function sendNotifications(docs) {
            var client = new twilio.RestClient(ACCOUNTSID, AUTHTOKEN);
            docs.forEach(function(appointment) {
                // Create options to send the message
                var options = {
                    to: "+1" + appointment.phoneNumber,
                    from: '+17755834363',
                    body: "Just a reminder that you have an appointment coming up  " + moment(appointment.time).calendar() +"."
                };

                // Send the message!
                client.sendMessage(options, function(err, response) {
                    if (err) {
                        // Just log it for now
                        console.error(err);
                    } else {
                        // Log the last few digits of a phone number
                        var masked = appointment.phoneNumber.substr(0,
                            appointment.phoneNumber.length - 5);
                        masked += '*****';
                        console.log('Message sent to ' + masked);
                    }
                });
            });

            // Don't wait on success/failure, just indicate all messages have been
            // queued for delivery
            if (callback) {
              callback.call(this);
            }
        }
    };
    var Appointment = mongoose.model('appointment', AppointmentSchema);
    module.exports = Appointment;
```

I have no idea why it's undefined, everything appears to be showing up fine in the db. And I don't know if this is what is causing the notifications to not actually be sent. I've been laboring over this for some time, if anyone has any insight that would be great.

File structure:

```
root
  ├ config
  | ├ auth.js
  | ├ database.js
  | ├ passport.js
  ├ controllers
  | ├appointments.js
  | ├routes.js
  ├ models
    ├appointment.js
    ├users.js
  ├ public
  ├ workers
    ├notificationsWorker
  ├ app.js
  ├ scheduler.js
```

Other relevant files to notifications:
appointments.js

```
var momentTimeZone = require('moment-timezone');
var Appointment = require('../models/appointment');
var moment = require('moment');

module.exports = function(app, client) {


app.post('/user', function(req, res, next) {
  var phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
  var notification = req.body.notification;
  var timeZone = req.body.timeZone;
  var time = moment(req.body.time, "MM-DD-YYYY hh:mma");

  var appointment = new Appointment({
    phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
    notification: notification,
    timeZone: timeZone,
    time: time
  });
  appointment.save()
    .then(function () {
      res.redirect('/user');
    });
});
```

notificationsWorker.js

```
var Appointment = require('../models/appointment')

var notificationWorkerFactory =  function(){
  return {
    run: function(){
      Appointment.sendNotifications();
    }
  };
};

module.exports = notificationWorkerFactory();
```

scheduler.js

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var notificationsWorker = require('./workers/notificationsWorker');
var moment = require('moment');

var schedulerFactory =  function(){
  return {
    start: function(){
      new CronJob('00 * * * * *', function() {
        console.log('Running Send Notifications Worker for ' +  moment().format());
        notificationsWorker.run();
      }, null, true, '');
    }
  };
};

module.exports = schedulerFactory();
```

And finally the app.js file:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({path: '.env'});
const exp = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); //body parser
const methodOverride = require('method-override'); //method override
const app = exp();
const session = require('express-session');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const fetchUrl = require('fetch').fetchUrl;
const request = require('request');
const sass = require('node-sass');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var appointments = require('./controllers/appointments');
var scheduler = require('./scheduler');


var ACCOUNTSID = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_ID;
var AUTHTOKEN = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;

var twilio = require('twilio');
var client = new twilio.RestClient(ACCOUNTSID, AUTHTOKEN);


//databse stuff
const db = require('./config/database.js');
// mongoose.connect(db.url); // connect to our database

//passport
const passport = require('passport');
const flash    = require('connect-flash');
app.use(session({ secret: 'blahblahblahbleck' })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

//views/middleware configs
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
  layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/',
  defaultLayout: 'main',
  partialsDir: [__dirname + '/views/partials/']
}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.locals.pretty = true
app.use('/', exp.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/bower_components',  exp.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
app.use(methodOverride('_method')) //method override
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
  // app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/imgages/favicon.ico'));
})); //body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json()); //body parser
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.locals.moment = require('moment');

require('./config/passport')(passport);
require('./controllers/routes')(app, passport);
require('./controllers/appointments')(app, client, db);

app.use('./controllers/appointments', appointments);
app.use('/', appointments);


// dynamically set controllers(routes)
fs.readdirSync('./controllers').forEach(function(file) {
    routes = require('./controllers/' + file);
});

//start the server
app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log('things that make you go hmmm on port ' + PORT);
});

scheduler.start();

module.exports = app;
```

**==================UPDATED=================**

My form input view:

```
 <form class="omb_loginForm" action="/" autocomplete="off" method="POST">

  <span class="help-block"></span>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="phone number">
  </div>

  <span class="help-block"></span>

  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="notification" placeholder="notification">
  </div>

  <span class="help-block"></span>

  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
    <select class="form-control" name="timeZone">
      {{#each timeZone}}
      <option>{{this}}</option>
      {{/each}}
    </select>
  </div>

  <span class="help-block"></span>

   <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
    <input class="form-control" name="time">
    <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon-calendar glyphicon">
    </span>
  </div>

  <span class="help-block"></span>


  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
  Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Original form view:

```
.form-group
  label.col-sm-4.control-label(for='inputName') Name *
  .col-sm-8
    input#inputName.form-control(type='text', name='name', placeholder='Name', required='', data-parsley-maxlength='20', data-parsley-maxlength-message="This field can't have more than 20 characters", value="#{appointment.name}")
.form-group
  label.col-sm-4.control-label(for='inputPhoneNumber') Phone Number
  .col-sm-8
    input#inputPhoneNumber.form-control(type='number', name='phoneNumber', placeholder='Phone Number', required='', value="#{appointment.phoneNumber}")
.form-group
  label.col-sm-4.control-label(for='time') Appointment Date
  .col-sm-8
    input#inputDate.form-control(type='text', name='time', placeholder='Pick a Date', required='', value="#{moment(appointment.time).format('MM-DD-YYYY hh:mma')}")
.form-group
  label.col-sm-4.control-label(for='selectNotification') Notification Time
  .col-sm-8
    select#selectDelta.form-control(name='notification', required='', value="#{appointment.notification}")
      option(selected=appointment.notification == '', value='') Select a time
      option(selected=appointment.notification == '15', value='15') 15 Minutes
      option(selected=appointment.notification == '30', value='30') 30 Minutes
      option(selected=appointment.notification == '45', value='45') 45 Minutes
      option(selected=appointment.notification == '60', value='60') 60 Minutes
.form-group
  label.col-sm-4.control-label(for='selectTimeZone') Time Zone
  .col-sm-8
    select#selectTimeZone.form-control(name='timeZone', required='', value="#{appointment.timeZone}")
      each zone in timeZones
        option()
option(selected=zone == appointment.timeZone, value="#{zone}") !{zone}
```

routes.js

```
app.get('/user', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
          res.render('user', {
              user : req.user,
              timeZone: timeZones(),
              appointment : new Appointment({
                phoneNumber: "",
                notification: '',
                timeZone: "",
                time:''}),
              loggedIn: true, // get the user out of session and pass to template
              layout: 'home'
          });
      });
```

Comment: It looks like the issue is happening in the `requiresNotification` method. Can you debug or log out that you are definitely getting `this.time` and `this.timeZone` correctly within that method. Also, you seem to be comparing the difference in the time of the notification and the time now in minutes to a string which is unlikely to ever be true, so your filter will return an empty array. What is that comparison supposed to be?

Comment: @philnash they are in fact both coming back as undefined. I think I'm beginning to see where the issue is regarding the comparison. In the original code, the notification value in the form is being used as the number of minutes before the appointment (15 minutes, 30 minutes, etc) the SMS reminder should be sent. My intention was to eliminate that and use the notification value as the actual body of the message, and for the SMS to be sent exactly at the time entered. I added the code from the original form and my form above. Trying to figure how to resolve this...

Comment: Are you getting all the values submitted correctly to your form action? And are they saving correctly? That's where I'd look (though I can't see anything that stands out as wrong right now).

Comment: They are getting saved correctly, if I console log a submission it comes up like this `{ phoneNumber: '342532535',
  notification: 'nblkjlkjaflkf',
  timeZone: 'US/Eastern',
  time: 2017-02-09T05:00:00.000Z,
  _id: 589cbac47a1240a69b39b1b0 }` If it's any help, the original tutorial code can be found [here](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/appointment-reminders-node)

Comment: So, if the submission is saved correctly, is it being retrieved correctly? I can't see any other reason for `this.time` not being set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally get it working by changing the logic around in `requiresNotification`. Here's the updated code:

```
AppointmentSchema.methods.requiresNotification = function (date) {
  var apptDate = moment.utc(this.time);
  var current = moment.utc(date);
  return Math.round(moment.duration(current.diff(apptDate))
    .asMinutes()) === 0;
};
```

I'm finding the duration of the difference between the appointment time and current time. So now when the difference in minutes of the **appointment** date/time and the **current** date/time is 0, the notification is sent.